# How to prove that the tetrahedron exist unique incentre?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, determinant

My approach:

Let the equations of 4 faces be

$\alpha_1:A_{11}x_1+A_{12}x_2+A_{13}x_3=B_1,$
$\alpha_2:A_{21}x_1+A_{22}x_2+A_{23}x_3=B_2$

$\alpha_3:A_{31}x_1+A_{32}x_2+A_{33}x_3=B_3,$
$\alpha_4:A_{41}x_1+A_{42}x_2+A_{43}x_3=B_4$

We want to find $X_1,X_2,X_3,d$ such that

$\frac{|A_{11}X_1+A_{12}X_2+A_{13}X_3-B_1|}{\sqrt(A_{11}^2+A_{12}^2+A_{13}^2)}=\frac{|A_{21}X_1+A_{22}X_2+A_{23}X_3-B_2|}{\sqrt(A_{21}^2+A_{22}^2+A_{23}^2)}   =\frac{|A_{31}X_1+A_{32}X_2+A_{33}X_3-B_3|}{\sqrt(A_{31}^2+A_{32}^2+A_{33}^2)}=\frac{|A_{41}X_1+A_{42}X_2+A_{43}X_3-B_4|}{\sqrt(A_{41}^2+A_{42}^2+A_{43}^2)}=d$

which is equivalent to solve the homogenous equation
\begin{align*}
  A_{11}X_1+A_{12}X_2+A_{13}X_3 -d*\sqrt(A_{11}^2+A_{12}^2+A_{13}^2) &= \,B_1 \\ 
  A_{21}X_1+A_{22}X_2+A_{23}X_3 -d*\sqrt(A_{21}^2+A_{22}^2+A_{23}^2) &= \,B_2 \\ 
  A_{31}X_1+A_{32}X_2+A_{33}X_3 -d*\sqrt(A_{31}^2+A_{32}^2+A_{33}^2) &= \,B_3 \\ 
  A_{41}X_1+A_{42}X_2+A_{43}X_3 -d*\sqrt(A_{41}^2+A_{42}^2+A_{43}^2) &= \,B_4 \\ 
\end{align*}

so,if I could prove that the determinant

\begin{vmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} & -\sqrt(A_{11}^2+A_{12}^2+A_{13}^2)
 \\ A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23} & -\sqrt(A_{21}^2+A_{22}^2+A_{23}^2) 
\\A_{31} & A_{32} & A_{33} & -\sqrt(A_{31}^2+A_{32}^2+A_{33}^2) 
\\A_{41} & A_{42} & A_{43} & -\sqrt(A_{41}^2+A_{42}^2+A_{43}^2) 
\\ \end{vmatrix} not equal to zero than by cramer's rule the equations has only 1 roots,which means that the tetrahedron has only 1 incentre.Any hints for me to prove the determinant is not zero?

Comment: Another way to think it through: For tetrahedron $OABC$, consider planes that bisect the dihedral angles along $\overline{AB}$, $\overline{BC}$, and $\overline{CA}$. Points on the first plane are equidistant from the planes $OAB$ and $ABC$; likewise, points on the other planes are equidistant from a corresponding pair of planes. Consequently, a point is an incenter iff its equidistant from all four faces iff it lies on all three planes. Therefore, the incenter is the (necessarily unique) point common to the three planes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last determinant can be $0$. This is the case for:

$$\det\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}1&0&1&-\sqrt{2}\\-1&0 &1 &-\sqrt{2}\\0 &-1 &1 &-\sqrt{2}\\0 &1& 1 &-\sqrt{2}\end{array}\right)=0$$